Identify this movie: Blonde woman shot in front of school
I forgot the genre, but it was recent (last decade) and set in the US. There was this annoying senior year high school student who was sitting in a luxury car outside of High School talking on her mobile phone when a guy came up and executed her.
I think it might have been a comedy movie, but don't remember very well.

Is it God Bless America?  It came out in 2011.

This is definitely it. Great find.

I remember the trailer - I thought it was an interesting idea for a black comedy.

FYI this is a very similar concept to the movie with the Crimson Bolt hero who kills everyday people (black comedy).
